# How can I make a div dynamically change to content width and have it remain that width even as the browser window changes size?

Tags: html, css, width

Take a look at this: (Scenario 1)

```
#container {
    height:150px;
    border:1px solid pink;
    width:1100px;
}
#widget {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DQFja/1/

Very simple. A div with a bunch of other divs within it. Parent div has a fixed width of ~1000 pixels, children divs are set to display:inline-block; When you make the browser window smaller than the parent, a scroll bar appears and you can scroll to see the rest.

Now take a look at this: (Scenario 2)

```
#container {
    height:150px;
    border:1px solid pink;
    float:left;
}
#widget {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zZRq7/

Same parent and children, but the width of the parent is dynamically determined by the number of div children you place in it. Which is dandy. However, when you make the browser window smaller, the parent div becomes as wide as the window and the children start wrapping around, making the parent taller (Even though we set a fixed height!)

How do I make the parent `div` BOTH dynamic in width as in scenario 2, but then also keep its shape/height/width when the browser window gets smaller so we can get a scrollbar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Min-width` is the way to go:

```
#container {
    height:150px;
    border:1px solid pink;
    min-width:1100px; // set the minimum width of the container to 1100px
    width: 100%; // if the window size is bigger than 1100px, then make the container span the entire window
}
```

See a live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DQFja/2/).

A hacky way to achieve is using the `white-space` property as follows:

```
#container {
    border:1px solid pink;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#widget {
    display: inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
}​
```

See a live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DQFja/4/)

Comment: Yeah I was a little confused "dynamic in width... but also keep its shape/height/width". hopefully one of ours is what he was looking for :)

Comment: this works fine, until you add more widgets/children into the parent. then we have the same problem again! what I need is a fixed width that sets itself automatically. maybe this should be done in javascript? (count the # of children and set parent width accordingly?)

Comment: the hack answer WORKS!!! thank you SO MUCH! I'd upvote this but I don't have the reputation hahaha.

Answer (score 2):

Updating answer to include the white-space line:

```
#container {
    height:150px;
    border:1px solid pink;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DQFja/3/

Comment: `overflow:auto;`  will be most appropriate here. You only want to see scroll-bars when there's an overflow ;)

Comment: this gives me a scroll bar within the parent div to scroll vertically.  what I want is for the browser window to give me a horizontal scroll bar instead of resizing the div

Comment: If that's the case, then the other answer is probably what you are looking for... or is it that you don't want the min-width to be 1100px, you just always want the width as it is determined children elements?

Comment: Since this wasn't the answer (overflow:auto) you're look for, I'm updating with my last attempt.

Comment: this gives me a scrollbar in the parent DIV, rather than the browser window. jacktheripper got it, thanks!