# min-width css is not working

Tags: html, css

I have a form and I put the max width to 600 px it works perfectly,when the user submits the form and there are errors, I created the form again with the error message each to the input field.

the problem is that I want the form to expand where there are error messages.

#### What have I tried

I google the problem and I found this question [How do I make a div dynamically change to content width AND have it remain that width even as the browser window changes size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388257/how-do-i-make-a-div-dynamically-change-to-content-width-and-have-it-remain-that)

I tried it like this:

```
.inputForm{
    min-width:600px;
    width: 100%;
```

with removing the max-width of course, but that just make the form as if the width 100%.

This is a jsfiddle before submitting

http://jsfiddle.net/e9Y4w/

This is the jsfiddle after submitting:
http://jsfiddle.net/e9Y4w/1/

Comment: Please be specific. What do you want to be expanded? Input element, error message or whole form?

Comment: @Aleksandar sorry I thought I did, the form of course

Comment: why not use the min-width and the max-width only?

Comment: @StevoPerisic If i used max width = 900 or 100 only, the form would look ugly when it created in the first place where no error messages are in it

Comment: Maybe a valid HTML  and a rethink of what margin:0 50%; might do will help :)

Comment: I can make a jQuery solution, which will check if a field is empty, and then throw an error message if you like..

Comment: @JiFus no thanks I already build error api thanks

Comment: @GCyrillus I used margin 0 50% just in the submit button to make it in the middle horizantally. that doesn't affect the form width i guess

Comment: You are using width 100% - any wider and it will cause your form to require horizontal scrolling... take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/e9Y4w/4/)... still has a lot of work to go and needs some formatting love, but it demonstrates solving your issue with floats and percentage widths -- [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/e9Y4w/4/)

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli oki , what about cleaning up html ? so browsers do not try themselves sample of your code :             `<select="select="  date=" " function="" day="" first="Day First" month="" year="" name="date_function_id">` ... funny way to dispatch quotes :)  . See with margin:0 50% removed : http://jsfiddle.net/e9Y4w/8/

Comment: @GCyrillus that selects bothers me a lot but I don't know how to fix it. it is generated automatically using Laravel framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're setting a % width on your inputs. Change it to a specific pixel width like so:

```
.inputForm input[type="text"], .inputForm input[type="email"], .inputForm textarea, .inputForm select {
...
width: 420px; /*70%;*/
...
}
```

Then change your form to be an inline-block so that it will auto-size the width and add in your min-width:

```
.inputForm{
min-width:600px;
display: inline-block;
/* width: 100%; */
/* max-width: 600px; */
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to stop the text wrapping of the required field text.

To do this simply add the below to your form:

```
 .inputForm{
       min-width:600px;
       white-space: nowrap;
       display: inline-block;
...
```

This stops it from wrapping the text and makes sure the container grows with the text if the display is small enough, this is done with the inline-block.

I also added a min-width to the `input["text"]` fields. But that's personal preference.

http://jsfiddle.net/e9Y4w/3/

Comment: so you editing is this  white-space: nowrap; and displa inline block , i tried that but that makes the text out of the form but the form doesn't expand to it

Comment: +1 to your efforts but the other ansewr helped me more. really thanks

Comment: Sorry, it worked for me. That's no problem, I'm glad you got your solution.