# Center Element in DIV without Cutting Off Left Content if Element Becomes Wider than Window

Tags: javascript, html, css

Refer to: https://jsfiddle.net/bu6L8q3p/

In my example, when you reduce the width of the window the content gets cut off on the left side.  I would like the scroll bar when needed but the content to shift so the table left edge position doesn't go negative. In this case, the table is not centered.

The content will be dynamic (text length) and mobile/desktop cases is the reason for it.  Is the only solution dynamic Javascript to set based on window width?  Is there another way to center the table element without using left: -50% ?

```
<div class="emergencyContainer">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="emergencyCol1"><h3>Service:</h3></td>
      <td class="emergencyCol2"><h3><a target="_blank" href="tel:1-800-555-5555">1-800-555-5555</a></h3></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="emergencyCol1"><h3>Website:</h3></td>
      <td class="emergencyCol2"><h3><a target="_blank" href="http://www.test.com">http://www.test.com/</a></h3></td>
    </tr>
  </table></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.emergencyCol1 {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  text-align:right;
    height: 1.5em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.emergencyCol2 {
    margin:0;
    padding-left: 0.3em;
    text-align: left;
    height: 1.5em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.emergencyContainer{
  float: right;

  position: relative;
  left: -50%; 
  text-align: left;
}
.emergencyContainer > table {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;

}
```

Comment: So basically,you need a scrollbar when window is smaller than page ?

Comment: Scrollbar is working, but the left contents gets chopped off even with the scrollbar. In the fiddle, adjust the window so it's small and you will see.

Comment: Check out the answer @Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this code. I changes only emergencycontainer and table css

```css
.emergencyCol1 {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
  text-align:right;
 height: 1.5em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.emergencyCol2 {
 margin:0;
 padding-left: 0.3em;
 text-align: left;
 height: 1.5em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.emergencyContainer{
  overflow:auto;
}
.emergencyContainer > table {
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="emergencyContainer">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="emergencyCol1"><h3>Service:</h3></td>
      <td class="emergencyCol2"><h3><a target="_blank" href="tel:1-800-555-5555">1-800-555-5555</a></h3></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="emergencyCol1"><h3>Website long:</h3></td>
      <td class="emergencyCol2"><h3><a target="_blank" href="http://www.test.com">http://www.test.com/extra/long/now/fit</a></h3></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript helps a lot when you need to resize depending on if an element is being displayed or not, for example lateral bars. As you said, you could resize dynamically your table as window gets resized. Yes, add an `onresize` event to window and set the container (even the body) width value as a percentage value of the `window.innerWidth` attribute.

Believe me. setting percentages don't do the trick. And what I'm thinking about is that those events that changes styles, like resizing the window, are controlled by JavaScript events. I don't really think CSS is dynamic. Even tho, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388257/how-do-i-make-a-div-dynamically-change-to-content-width-and-have-it-remain-that) to see if it does the trick for you (or writing the script I wrote above)